# Xcode Architecture issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, cocoapods

I am using `xcode 6.4` in my project, it contains cocoapods where Pods are as follows:

```
pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 3.0'    
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'    
pod 'iRate'    
pod 'NewRelicAgent'    
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'    
pod 'Appirater'    
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

But, after I update my pods I am getting the error which I attached to this image: [Error is becuase of one pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88aPx.png)

Comment: have you specified latest versions of frameworks in the pod file?

Comment: hi Thanks for saw question.

Comment: In My pod file error is because of NewRelicAgent framework. And in Pod for NewRelicAgent i didn't write version in pod file.

Comment: Then try to add version of NewRelicAgent framework

Comment: But i use this framework Through Cocoa pod.And in Cocoa pod not mention about framework version for NewRelicAgent

Comment: Have you followed the correct instructions given in this link ?: https://cocoapods.org/pods/NewRelicAgent

Comment: Finally i get solution of this problem.

Comment: For that you need to add file add .pch file with your Project Name.

Comment: and add   #ifdef __OBJC__
#import <NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h>
 #endif "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need One project prefix header file
 [image: .pch file code]

And add in bulid setting this .pch file.

Answer (score 0):

So 
**FOR OBJECTIVE_C**

yes this podfile should work,

**FOR SWIFT add,this line too**

use_frameworks!

YOU DON'T HAVE TO MENTION THE VeRSION OF ANY LIBRARY IF NOT MENTIONED ON COCOAPODS.

Lastly if you have taken care of all these
then try cleaning project **cmd 
+ shift+ k** and then run project.

If still not working then delete manually the dependencies folders and reinstall them

**# if there is problem with Google MobileAds-ios-Sdk, then you are stuck. Because there is some problem with them, and hence it would be better to install Google MobileAds-ios-Sdk manually only**